# PHP File Exist Error - Checking Outside?

Tags: php, file

Im currently using Windows 7 with WAMP server installed. Im trying to do a simple PHP "file exist" command but for some reason, its working alot differently.... Here is my code:

```
if(file_exists('\prop\sys\config.txt')) {
echo 'exist';
} else {
echo 'dont exist';
}
```

Simple as it sounds, even though the file actually exists, PHP is coming back with a dont exist. This baffled me at first but when I try to make PHP check a file on my actual computer like:

```
if(file_exists('C:\Users\PeopleUser\Desktop\f.txt')) {
echo 'exist';
} else {
echo 'dont exist';
}
```

Surprisingly enough, it came back as true! So that means WAMP is checking OUTSIDE of the folder its supposed to be in. I tried enabling "safe mode" and restarted WAMP and it still does not work, I also disabled "expose PHP" to also try to stop it. Its not working and PHP will freely check my computer.


How can I stop this?

Comment: better to use [`is_readable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side process with access to the host's filesystem. Any path you specify is a filesystem path.

You're better off constructing a path relative to the PHP file. For example, say the file containing your code is in the document root (the same folder containing the `prop` folder)

```
$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/prop/sys/config.txt');

if (file_exists($path)) {
    // and so on
```

Comment: @SteveLaster My answer is just an example. What are the absolute locations (on your hard disk) of the PHP script and `config.txt`?

Comment: C:\wamp\www\prop\sys\config.txt

Comment: @SteveLaster I asked for the location of your PHP script as well